# Load data from SQL file to Realm

Tags: ios, iphone, realm

Is it possible to have a SQL file inside Swift project where Realm database will import data as soon as project will be executed? I want to use a 30MB+ file of data... and don't want to download it all from a JSON API.

Answer (score 0):

Why not [bundle a prebuilt Realm file](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#other-realms) as part of your application instead? To do this you'll need to:

1. Create the prebuilt Realm file, either using Realm Browser or a simple Mac app of your own creation.
2. Add the prebuilt Realm file to your app target in your Xcode project, ensuring that it appears in the Copy Bundle Resources build phase.
3. Add code similar to that found in the above link to your app to have it open the prebuilt Realm file as read-only. Alternatively, you could copy the file out of your app bundle into the user's documents or cache directory and open it read-write.

Comment: Is that that Other Realms thread? Could you provide me some better example? I am quite lost here..

Comment: I added more detail.